# Driver to print from a Cannon imageCLASS MF244dw on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, printing, samba, canon

I'm unable to find a driver for a Canon imageCLASS MF244dw on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I found a rather old ppa for this but it doesn't appear to work I get the following after adding it as a repository and running apt-get:

```
W: The repository 'https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, I don't really [see the printer on the list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon).  If I share the printer via a machine that has the drivers (a Windows machine) over Samba would it still be possible to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the procedure [here](https://wiki.debian.org/PrinterDriver/Canon/UFR-II)...

1. [Downloaded the drivers](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0100005950/04/Linux_UFRIILT_PrinterDriver_V130_uk_EN.tar.gz).

   1. Extracted it...

      1. In the extracted directory went to `Linux_UFRIILT_PrinterDriver_V130_uk_EN/64-bit_Driver/Debian`
      2. Tried to install both files...they didn't work...
      3. Ran `apt-get -f install`
      4. Installed both files with `dpkg -i *.deb`
2. Visited http://localhost:631
3. Clicked the `Find New Printers` button.
4. The new printer came up in the list (it was connected to the network).
5. When the `make` list was displayed, selected `Cannon`.
6. Clicked `continue`
7. In the list of drivers found `LBP151 UFRII LT ver.1.3` or `UFRII LT ver.1.3` or something like that...
8. Clicked `Next`
9. Selected the defaults for the printer.
10. Clicked `Finished`
11. The printer appeared in the Ubuntu list of printers...
12. Printed a test page...it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Although the top link is down, I searched for those drivers and got this: https://asia.canon/en/support/0100924010  Downloaded and used the 64bit cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.60-1.08_amd64.deb drivers on my ubuntu system. The deb installer pops up a printer window to install. I have a Canon MF244 multifuntion printer, so I used I think the mf240 (can't remember exactly).  All works except getting 1200dpi working, but I'll work on that later.